# .net json property conversion in java - @JsonProperty

Tags: java, .net, json, rest, annotations

Need some help here! I have a Java Rest API which is getting data from a .net endpoint and passing it on to the UI. The JSON properties are in capital case and I want to convert them in JAVA before sending it to the UI. Any pointers on this?

In java, I have a class like below:

```
public class Person {
@JsonProperty("Name")
private String name;
@JsonProperty("Age")
private int age;
}
```

I am using @JsonProperty as keys in .net are starting with capitalCase. How can I convert this back before sending it to the UI in Java?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What do you mean by *convert them in JAVA*?

Comment: In java my endpoint returns, {"Name": "XXX", "Age": 11}. I want it to be {"name": "XXX", "age": 11}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create another class with the same structure and use there other names that you want. Something like this:

```
// Class to read .NET object
public class Person {
    @JsonProperty("Name")
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty("Age")
    private int age;
}

// Class to represent the object in Java REST API
public class Person {
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty("age")
    private int age;
}


// Class to represent the object in Java REST API,
// in case you use some standard library that
// uses property names for JSON as is
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;
}
```

Of course you should put these classes into different packages.

Your code can look as follows:

```
xxx.dotnet.Person dotnetPerson = doSomethingViaDotNet(...);
yyy.rest.Person restPerson = new yyy.rest.Person();
restPerson.setName(dotnetPerson.getName());
restPerson.setAge(dotnetPerson.getAge());
...
return restPerson;
```

If you decide to use [MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org/), your code may looks as follows:

```
@Mapper
public interface PersonMapper {
    PersonMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper( PersonMapper.class );

    yyy.rest.Person dotnetToRest(xxx.dotnet.Person dotnetPerson);
}
```

Since all attributes have the same names and types you don't need anything else in your mapper.

MapStruct will generate a class that implements this interface. Usage will be as follows:

```
restPerson = PersonMapper.INSTANCE.dotnetToRest(dotnetPerson);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Was thinking if I can do something with dozer but have never used it. Any thoughts?

Comment: Dozer is OK. I personally prefer MapStruct. If you need to map 5-10 classes and if you have 50-100 users, it doesn't matter. If you have 10 000 users, then MapStruct *might* be faster. What I like most, is that with MapStruct you have (generated) source code *explicitly for every setter call for every propery*. It is very convenient during debugging.

Comment: Is MapStruct what you have done in the above example? I have around 15 attributes that come from .net and I only need to change 5 of them. Should I use setters for each of them like how to gave in your example above?

Comment: No, my example is for the case when you everything do manually, without any libraries. In MapStruct, if all properties have the same names and type, you need to write only *one* line like *restPerson = mapper.toRestPerson(dotnerPerson);*.

Comment: Using MapStruct worked like magic for me! Thanks a lot @mentallurg!!

Comment: @user3358472: Glade to know that :)